# How do I install Get Windows 10 app while joined to a domain

Tags: administrator, domain, windows-server-2012, windows-10-upgrade

The app installation seems to be blocked from installation by Microsoft if the computer is joined to a domain.  Microsoft says the usual "contact your domain administrator" to allow this but I cannot find anything for those of us who administer our own home server to tell us how to allow this installation.  It would be nice to allow each computer to check for compatibility prior to the July 29th launch.  As far as I know, that is the current function of this app.  I really do not want to remove each computer from the domain just to do a software compatibility check.  Has anyone found a better solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Offer Icon (GWX) - How to get it on AD/Domain joined PCs?](http://superuser.com/questions/923104/windows-10-offer-icon-gwx-how-to-get-it-on-ad-domain-joined-pcs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Will domain joined non volume license Windows Pro clients receive the upgrade offer?

> Domain Joined computers are not supported at this time unfortunately.
> Your best option is to download the .ISO file and upgrade the
> computers manually/offline.
>
> **How will Domain Joined computers that are not volume license clients
> be able to check their systems and reserve the Windows 10 upgrade?**
>
> You will need to use Enterprise Assessment tools for the range of
> computers you have. The reservation app does not work in complex IT
> environments.
>
> Microsoft is likely to release a new version of its Microsoft
> Assessment and Planning Toolkit (MAP) that will support Windows 10. It
> can help you quickly inventory small or large IT environments without
> requiring you to install any agent software in your environment.
>
> Watch this blog for updates to know when it will be available with
> support for Windows 10.
>
> http://blogs.technet.com/b/mapblog/

Source [Frequently Asked Questions: Windows 10](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/frequently-asked-questions-windows-10/5c0b9368-a9e8-4238-b1e4-45f4b7ed2fb9)