# Upgrading Windows 7/8.1 Pro PC that are on a domain to Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

With less tan a month till Windows 10 is released, I wanted to know the upgrade process for PC that are on Windows 7/8.1 Pro but are joined to a domain.

Currently, I dont see the icon (normal, Microsoft has disabled this for domains) but I want to know if this will change in the future.

I dont see upgrading all our PCs (I have to do testing with the software we use and see compatibility) but after a couple of years, Ill problably be upgrading PC by PC and each new PC we get, will problably come with Windows 10. On a good side, we have Windows Server 2012 R2 which will problably be compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: Hey! This question is pretty huge really, there are a lot of methods and a lot of ways to get Windows 10 licensing within an enterprise environment. You can roll it out manually, using PXE or moving to a VDI environment which is personally what I would do....  Personally I would never roll out an 'upgrade' path in a corporate environment, users data should be stored on the network so swapping users machines from a Windows 7/8.1/10 should be as simple as adding it to the Domain and letting them login.

Comment: Well, could you give a short explaination on how to do each one? I seem to not be able to download the KB upgrade manually and distribute to my machines (manual), doing it via PXE would be manually as well but just boot a image off a server (PXE) and VDI for a small business is not something really intresting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Get Windows 10 app while joined to a domain](http://superuser.com/questions/927606/how-do-i-install-get-windows-10-app-while-joined-to-a-domain)

Answer (score 0):

At present, the Windows 10 App has not been rolled out to domain machines and this is unlikely to change. (See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/frequently-asked-questions-windows-10/5c0b9368-a9e8-4238-b1e4-45f4b7ed2fb9)

Your options are fairly limited in terms of an automated rollout - but are also no different to any other OS rollout:

- Disjoin machines from the domain in small groups, upgrade and then rejoin (sounds stupid, but i have a client who is actually doing this for several hundred machines!)
- Download the Windows 10 ISO and peform the upgrades my mounting the ISO and running the installer
- PXE/Reimage/rebuild machines as Windows 10

Which route you go down would rely heavily on the nature of your business (size of machines, how widely distributed they are geographically, availability to take them offline for a few hours)

Comment: Thank you for a OK answer. I would most likely do a combo of #2 but with PXE booting. Like I mention, I dont plan to do a rollout but I should be able to have a plan ready when I do.

Comment: That'll be your way to go then... trial a couple of machines of iso/pxe and if its good, make sure to document it and away you go! (you know.. when you're ready!)

Comment: There is a fourth option.  Wait until the release and use the offline method to upgrade to Windows 10.  There will be a method to do that.  Microsoft has said there will be a method to get an .iso file.  How you will claim your license rights for Windows 10 with this method is yet to be seen though.

Comment: @Ramhound That answer has already been posted. I already said that is the method I am going to use: ISO on PXE and boot PCs from there.

Comment: @riahc3 - I don't normally read comments.  You are indeed right though.  The answer does contain that solution.  Comment was directed towards the community though.

Comment: @Ramhound It wasnt a comment. It was added as a answer by Fazer87.